# Should the loss terms in diffusion model training be weighted by the diffusion schedule?

Tags: neural-networks, diffusion

I'm following [Understanding Diffusion Models](https://arxiv.org/abs/2208.11970) to write my own diffusion model training code. I'm working based off the loss showed in equation 58

[image]

In equation 99, a useful form of the individual terms in the denoising matching summation is shown:

[image]

When I saw this my knee jerk reaction was to write a function like:

```py
def loss(x0, x0hat):
    return torch.mean((x0 - x0hat) ** 2)
```

and this worked, in that I was able to generate MNIST digits after training my model.

But then I realised two things:

1. The denoising matching terms need the coefficient:
   [image]. I plotted this out over a typical alpha schedule and it looks like a meaningful change (coefficients for lower t are much larger) [image]
2. For t=1 we are actually supposed to look at the reconstruction term, for which the coefficient is 1.

So I made the relevant changes.

```py
def training_loss(self, x0hat: FloatTensor, x0: FloatTensor, t: LongTensor):
    """Compute loss following eqns 58 and 99."""
    t_view = t.view(-1, *([1] * (x0.ndim - 1)))
    # This is the loss for each of the elements of the batch. For t=1 the coefficient is 1 as we are considering the
    # reconstruction term. For t>=2 we use the coefficient in eqn 99.
    total_loss = torch.sum(
        torch.where(t_view >= 2, self.kld_coeff[t_view - 1], 1) * (x0hat - x0) ** 2, dim=tuple(range(1, x0.dim()))
    )
    # Now considering eqn 58, we see that each of the loss terms in the batch have equal weighting, so we can safely
    # just take a mean now.
    return total_loss.mean()
```

But training the diffusion model is not so nice now, as in the generated MNIST digits don't looks so realistic.

I noticed that at least one open source implementation of diffusion models uses the first, simpler variant of the loss that I wrote above. But wouldn't the second variant be more correct?